# Bash: Launch a notification reguraly to remind a process is waiting to end

Tags: linux, bash

I've an alias in my bashrc who shutdown my VPN wait to press a key and then launch my VPN again.
But sometimes I forgot to press the key to relaunch my VPN, so what I try to do is reguraly (every 2 minutes for example) I want a notification to remind me that my VPN is OFF).

The alias

```
alias vpnd='sudo net down && read -n1 -p"Press a key to reactivate the VPN..." && sudo net up'
```

And the net command

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

[[ ( "$1" == "up" ) || ( "$1" == "down" ) ]] && wg-quick "$1" wg0 &> /dev/null
```

I know the notify-send command, the sleep command, but don't know how to combine them for make it working.
Ideally, if I could avoid an external process and have all in a single line of alias, it would be the must

Thanks for any suggestions

Edit 1: the purpose of this alias is to temporally deactivate my VPN for access some websites who block you if you use a VPN. So it's just for a few minutes.And I like how it works today, just want to add a reminder

Edit 2: Thanks to @freeman, for the help. The alias is like this now:

```
alias vpnd='sudo net down && echo "Press a key to reactivate the VPN..." && while true; do sleep 120; read -t 1 -n 1 && sudo net up && break || [[ $(ip a | grep -q "wg0") ]] || notify-send -t 2000 -i "/usr/share/icons/Contrast\
High/256x256/status/software-update-urgent.png" "WARNING" "VPN idle"; done'
```

Comment: Easier (most of all: Easier to debug) write a function instead of an alias. Inside the function, you can do a loop. BTW, if you do a `read -t 120 ....`, the _read_ will wait for 2 minutes and if nothing has been entered by then, it terminates with exit code 128.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't want the read command to terminate by himself. I want to press a button to close it. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit your alias to include a loop that runs every 2 minutes and checks if the VPN is active, and sends a notification if it is not

check this out :

```
alias vpnd='sudo net down && while true; do sleep 120; sudo net up; [[ $(sudo netstat -nr | grep -q "0.0.0.0") ]] || notify-send "VPN is OFF"; done'
```

**UPDATE** according to your comment, if you press any key within 1 second during the loop, it will immediately relaunch the VPN. Otherwise, if the VPN is still not active after 2 minutes, it will send a notification

```
alias vpnd='sudo net down && while true; do sleep 120; read -t 1 -n 1 && sudo net up || [[ $(sudo netstat -nr | grep -q "0.0.0.0") ]] || notify-send "VPN is OFF"; done'
```

**UPDATE 2**
according to your comment, the reason the alias does not terminate is because the while loop is set to run indefinitely,so you can edit your alias to include a condition that will break the loop once the VPN is reactivated

```
alias vpnd='sudo net down && while true; do sleep 120; read -t 1 -n 1 && sudo net up && break || [[ $(ifconfig | grep -q "tun0") ]] || notify-send "VPN is OFF"; done'
```

Comment: yes, but I want the possibility to start the VPN by just pressing a touch

Comment: @Trev0r07 ok just edit the alias to include a condition that checks if a key is pressed before relaunching the VPN ! I will update my answer.

Comment: That's better, but (yes, there is another one, no, two in facts): I need to type my password to run the netstat command (I'll find a workaround),the command don't terminate, even if I press a touch, the VPN start again, but I need to type CTRL+C to end the alias. If you can help, I will for sure choose your answer as the solution :-)

Comment: @Trev0r07 The rule of this website states that you can only ask one question at a time and you cannot expand on the original question you asked. If you have a new question, please open a new topic and provide me with the link so that I can assist you. Also, if your issue has been resolved at this stage, please mark it as resolved. However, if you still have a question related to the original one you asked, please go ahead and ask.

Comment: all right. Your solution did not work like I want: the alias don't terminate, I should type CTRL+C to end it.

Comment: @Trev0r07 check my answer again, it terminate the alias once the VPN is successfully reactivated, and it will only send a notification if the VPN is still not active after 2 minutes, I also removed `netstat`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, just replace ifconfig by the "new" command ip address, change tun0 to my interface name, add some cosmetics. All good.